# If $X,Y$ are rv's with continous densities $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and assume $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)/g(x)=0$; Is then $P(X \geq x)/P(Y \geq x+c)=0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is basically already written;

If $X,Y$ are continuous random variables with continous densities $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and assume
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)/g(x)=0$$

Is it then true that for any fixed constant $c>0$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\mathbb P(X \geq x)/P(Y \geq x+c)=0$$

as well?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hi there; Thanks for the warm welcome; The problem is that I do not really know if it is true or not so I do not know if I should try to find a counter example or a proof..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Below is a counterexample.

Let $f(x) = \phi(x + 1), g(x) = \phi(x)$, where $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ is the density of the standard normal distribution (i.e., take $X \sim N(-1, 1), Y \sim N(0, 1)$). It is easy to see that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} 
= \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x - 1/2} = 0.
\end{align}
Take $c = 1$, by L'Hôpital's rule,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{P(X \geq x)}{P(Y \geq x + 1)} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x + 1)} = 
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\phi(x + 1)}{\phi(x + 1)} = 1 \neq 0.  
\end{align}